# FTP Acesso externo Amazon ec2 Windows Server

Tags: iis, ftp, amazon-aws

Eu tenho uma instância do Windows Server 2016 t2.micro, na amazon ec2. Instalei o IIS com suporte FTP. Eu segui essa guia para colocar meu ftp acessível externamente:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=170411

Mas sem efeito, no filezilla eu consigo até "chegar" no endereço IP do ftp, mas nenhuma mensagem de boas-vindas é recebida, e a conexão fecha imediatamente.

Eu configurei os grupos de segurança de instâncias assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas somente as portas padrão continuam abertas, todas as outras que eu deifini ai não abrem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei por que ... Não sei mais o que fazer. Estou desesperado.

PS: HTTP (porta 80) funciona bem.

Comment: O Firewall do Windows está ativo?

Comment: Acabei de desativar, reiniciei e nada.. Parece algo com a listagem de diretórios do ftp ou o firewall la do ftp mesmo...

Comment: Basicamente isso acontece porque o FTP funciona de forma ativa e o EC2 só aceita conexões ftp de modo passivo. Para resolver isso você precisa configurar o IP público que você atribuiu para sua instancia no IIS, segue o link de como fazer isso: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings-in-iis-7#step-2-configure-the-external-ipv4-address-for-a-specific-ftp-site